# luaotfload can't find font "CMU Sans Serif Demi Condensed"

Tags: luaotfload

Luaotfload has problems finding a font that is installed in my texmf tree. The source:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\myfont={CMU Sans Serif Demi Condensed} at 10pt
\myfont
foo
\bye
```

The font is in `texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunssdc.otf` and kpsewhich finds it. What can I do now?

Edit: a sister font `{CMU Sans Serif Bold Extended Oblique}` works fine. Same directory...

Comment: Try searching for this font in the font database (a plain text file named `otfl-names.lua`, in the directory `\luatex-cache\generic\names` in one of your `texmf` trees). Maybe it has a slightly different name there, so it isn't found by your specification.

Comment: The name is from the database itself. So somehow `mkluatexfontdb` finds the font in the tree but luaotfload can't load it. It is taken from the `names.fullname` entry.

Comment: Not a solution, but to say that I see the same behaviour on the Mac and on Windows, both with TL 2010. `CMU Sans Serif Bold Extended Oblique` is found, but `CMU Sans Serif Demi Condensed` is not. I wonder therefore about the font file: it does seem to be that one that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well at first look in otfl-names.lua if the font is there and if you are using the correct name.

If the font is not there, the folder is not cached. Why and what to do about it depends on your system. `mkluatexfontdb --help` says:

```
Fonts are searched in directories on Windows or Linux that have been
searched with fontconfig.

On Mac OS X, only fonts located in the following standard font locations are
included in the font database:
    ~/Library/Fonts          /Library/Fonts
    /System/Library/Fonts    /Network/Library/Fonts
In particular, fonts installed in other locations with "Font Book" will not
be available.
```

Comment: The font _is_ in the database. Also fonts included in the texmf tree are included in the database (on all systems I guess, I am on OS X).

Comment: Why didn't you say directly that you already checked the database? Well the above message says that in OS X fonts in texmf trees are not available. I don't know why it is nevertheless in the database and I can't make tests as I have windows.

Comment: Of course I should have mentioned that directly. Didn't think about it. Sorry

Comment: @Urlike, no texmf tree is searched in all systems, the above message is misleading, I'll try to fix it when I've time (I'm half sleeping now).

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation for the strange behaviour of `luaotfload` at all, but for me (TeX Live 2010, Windows), the font is loaded when using exactly the same font name as `fc-list` does, which is `CMU Sans Serif Demi Condensed:style=DemiCondensed`:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\myfont={CMU Sans Serif Demi Condensed:style=DemiCondensed} at 10pt
\myfont
foo
\bye
```

works fine for me.

Comment: Also works for me on the Mac, even though it's not listed by `fc-list`!

Comment: @joseph: we don't use FontConfig on mac at all (on linux, we may read its configuration files if present), fonts in texmf tree are located using kpse.