# luaotfload can’t find fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, luaotfload

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows. `luaotfload` does not find the fonts located in the MiKTeX-maintained root directory (which is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\` on my system) and I am therefore unable to load them directly with `LuaLaTeX` and `fontspec`. My distribution and packages seem up-to-date; where could the problem come from?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

I know that `fontspec` loads Latin Modern fonts as the default fonts but specifying them manually should work; however, I get the following errors:

```
The font "LatinModernRoman" cannot be found.
The font "LatinModernSans" cannot be found.
The font "LatinModernMono" cannot be found.
```

It appears that, indeed, they are not in the database `otfl-names.lua`. And the situation is the same for all other fonts in MiKTeX directories. However, there is no problem with the fonts located in my local `TEXMF`: they do appear in the database and I can access them easily (well… not completely! — see my second question). I tried to play with the `OSFONTDIR` environment variable but got no luck. With XɘTeX, the previous example works fine (although fonts in local `TEXMF` “cannot be loaded by font name, only file name” [from `fontspec` documentation]).

I have a second question about fonts which, this time, **are** in the database `otfl-names.lua` but can’t be accessed directly by their full name because of their unusual `subfamily` parameter. This issue is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14580/12385) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26108/12385). It seems the situation has not changed, has it?

Any clarification on those points is welcome.

Comment: Hi Marc, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I removed the thanks. This is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed in the upvoting of helpful answers.

Comment: You may want to check if the problem persists if you provide exact file names, i.e., `\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf`, `\setsansfont{lmsans10-regular.otf}`, and `\setmonofont{lmmono10-regular.otf}`.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I’ll remember this. Thanks for the link (I assume it is O.K. here).

Comment: Of course. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Mico That works, indeed: the fonts can be accessed by their file name. However, it is quite a pain to have to use file names as the loading of variants (bold, italic, optical sizes, etc.) is not automatic (which is if you use font names). Is there any other solution? Anyway, thank you for your answer; at least, I can access the fonts.

Comment: Can someone please confirm this with a) TeX live 2012 or b) recent luaotfload+lualibs from github or c) another OS? Parentheses in directory names work fine in Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've finally found a solution (with the hint by Ulrike Fischer):
Simply edit (with administrator rights):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\luatex\lualibs\lualibs-dir.lua
```

And paste add these lines to the filter (around line 95) just before "P(1)"

```
P("(")  / "%%(" +
P(")")  / "%%)" +
```

The brackets will be escaped  and therefore the fonts in the "program files (x86)/miktex" folder can be found.

Comment: That seems to work fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are a few other characters that can cause problems: `[`, `%`, `^` and `$`. If they appear in a path, this path will not be usable. This is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: I've reported this alread in March, 2012 to Khaled Hosny

Answer (score 5):

Your example works fine for me on two PC with miktex 2.9.

Possible differences that come into my mind:

1. I don't have spaces in my pathes.
2. I have a single user installation.
3. At least one of the PC I'm using a unstable version of luaotfload
4. I have other fonts than you: This can affect the generation of the database.

I think you should at first run on the command line `mkluatexfontdb -vvv` to see which directories are actually searched and if there is somewhere a problem.

Comment: In my case, the example does **not** work on two different computers with MiKTeX 2.9. This is strange: the verbose option does indeed show that all the locations which _should_ be scanned _are_ scanned (recursively) but the script does **not** find fonts in directories that yet **do** contain fonts (like, getting back to my first example, `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/`, which contains the Latin Modern fonts). However, there are no errors; it just says: `0 'otf' fonts found` (and the same for `OTF`, `ttf`, `TTF`, `ttc`, `TTC`, `dfont`, `DFONT`).

Comment: You said that fonts in your local texmf are found. If you move one of the latin modern otf to this local texmf, is it found then? And the other way round: if you move on of the fonts of the local texmf to main tree: is it found then?

Comment: Yes, if I move the Latin Modern fonts to my local `TEXMF`, they are found and do appear in the database so that I can load them by their font name. But, if I put them back in their original location, as soon as I rebuild the database, they are not found any more. The same is true for other fonts.

Comment: I made some tests by renaming a local texmf tree: `mkluatexfontdb` doesn't like it if the name/path of the tree contains braces ` () `.

Comment: Hi, Ulrike, is it right, that the tool was renamed or something like that to `luaotfload-tool`? Maybe you like to update your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

For `Linux` this works if your new fonts are in `~/.fonts` and not being recognized by `mkluatexfontdb`:

```
 OSFONTDIR=${HOME}/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts//:/usr/share/texmf/fonts// mkluatexfontdb --force --verbose=-1 -vvv
```

Something similar ought to apply for Windows...